# Run time error in a c++ recursive program

Tags: c++, recursion, runtime, runtime-error

I try to solve a problem where you have a grid h*w , and multiple stamps 2^0,2^1,...,2^N and you need to tell the counting of the combinations possible, but im having a runetime error with my code.
Example:

3

1

3

Returns: 5

He has a 1x3 rectangle and 3 square stamps. The stamps' sides are 1, 2, and 4. The good sets of stamps are the following ones: (1,2), (1,2,4), (1,4), (2,4), and (4).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h> 

auto puissance(double N){
    double i=0.0;
    vector<double>listofp;
    while(i<N){
        listofp.push_back(pow(2.0,i));
        i++;
    }
    return listofp;
}

void cover(int N,int result) {
    //maybe i will  need to add another for loop to test out the other combinations
    vector<double>listofp=puissance(N);
    //is there a recursive way to add this suggested loop
    if(result==0){cout<<"+1";}
    for(int i=0;i<listofp.size();i++){
        cover(N,result-listofp[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    double N=3.0;
    int w=1;
    int h=3;
    int result=w*h;
    cover(N,result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your program does infinite recursion, which leads to stack overflow.

Comment: `i` is of type double; so you cannot use it as an iterator in `while(i<N)`.

Comment: putting the base case of result doesnt end the infinite loop?

Comment: Use the _two loops_ solution you considered. The problem is that `listofp.size()` never changes between the recusive calls.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ the thing i got the idea but i dont actually know how to implement it :(

Comment: @BatCoder You can use a double as an iterator, it just may not be as efficient as using an int.  **OP** you have an issue with storing a double value in an int vector (increase compiler warning level to flag this).

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm i have edited it but still, the problem i have is in the recursive call, i can normally not even go with the vector as a paramter and call the function puissance from there like ive just done,so thats not the problem too

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ   when calling puissance from thefunction it is even slower cause we call it in every recursive call, someone has done its recursive solution in java but i dont understand the language https://community.topcoder.com/stat?c=problem_solution&cr=10574855&rd=16569&pm=14011

Comment: @Tahtoh 'cover()' calls are not depend on 'result' values. So you get an infinite recursion.

Comment: @MaxPashkov can you ideone me a solution or explenation? i posted on here just cause i didn,t know how to do it

Comment: @Tahtoh your algorithm is not implemented correctly. It does not do what you want. This does not make it correct, but to avoid infinite recursion, test for result <= 0 in cover and then return.